# trying to make a custom shape with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

Want to make a physic body with a shape adapted to its texture.
Im doing it like explained in wwdc videos but im getting this exception:

```
    2014-06-11 16:42:05.673 jumps[536:60b] +[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:size:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x39b017b4
2014-06-11 16:42:05.681 jumps[536:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:size:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x39b017b4'
```

Doing this:

```
SKTexture *temp = _heroWalkingFrames[0]; //textures loaded from a .atlas folder
    SKSpriteNode *hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:temp];

    hero.name = @"hero";
    hero.zPosition = 1;
    [hero setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 220)];
    [hero setSize:CGSizeMake(25, 25)];

    //here I set the physicBody with the old way and still works: hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(23, 25)];

//this is the new way of doing but it throw exceptions :(
      hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:temp size:hero.size];

//or 
    //hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:temp alphaThreshold:0.1 size:hero.size];
```

Im doing this with x-code 6 and building it in an iphone 4...
Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install iOS 8 beta on that iPhone 4?

Comment: I didn't. I already tried an sklightNode wich is a new feature of spritekit and it worked well.

Comment: You were lucky perhaps. Generally to use new features you have to install the new os.

Comment: You were right, I just remembered that I was doing that test in the simulator instead of in the iphone 4... I just did that test in the simulator and is not throwing any exception. Thanks a lot mate :)